# Error when using python-kaleido from R to convert plotly graph to static image

Tags: python, r, plotly, reticulate

I am trying to use the R reticulate package to convert a plotly graph to a static image. I am using save_image/kaleido.

[Link to documentation for save_image / kaleido](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/plotly/html/save_image.html)

Initial setup:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
reticulate::install_miniconda()
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate-test', 'python-kaleido')
reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate-test', 'plotly', channel = 'plotly')
reticulate::use_miniconda('r-reticulate-test')
```

Here is my (buggy) attempt:

```
> library(plotly)
> p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10)
> save_image(p,"test.png")
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#histogram
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>
```

My query is : How do I fix the error that the name 'sys' is not defined?

Funnily, if I do :

```
> reticulate::repl_python()
Python 3.10.6 (/root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate-test/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.26.9000 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
Enter 'exit' or 'quit' to exit the REPL and return to R.
>>> import sys
>>> exit
> save_image(p,"test.png")
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'histogram' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#histogram
>
```

then it works and produces the picture that I am seeking.

Can someone tell me why I need to invoke repl_python, then import sys and exit it ? How can I fix this ? I need this since I need to create an automated script to create graphs.

Comment: This has to do with your Python environment. You can see what environments you have set up with `reticulate::virtualenv_list()` (no parameters needed). I've dubbed myself 'allergic' to the stifling nature of any variation of Anaconda. However, an env is an env. You can specify an env with `reticulate::use_virtualenv` or `reticulate::use_condaenv` or `reticulate::use_miniconda`. Once you confirm which env you're using (or want to use), you can check for pkgs in env with `reticulate::py_list_packages`. Use help for the parameters (based on env).  I don't have sys in my env; it still worked.

Comment: In the section marked "Initial Setup", the last line is : use_miniconda("r-reticulate-test") so I ***am*** specifying the environment. Also I think sys is a "base library" in python. It is ***always*** present. (That's why you don't have sys in your environment and it ***still*** works.)

Comment: This seems to be a regression in reticulate 1.26, see [issue #2179](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2179) in the plotly R package repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Salim B pointed out there is a [workaround documented](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2179) to call `import sys` in Python before executing `save_img()`:

```
p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10)
reticulate::py_run_string("import sys")
save_image(p, "./pic.png")
```

Comment: [Appears to be fixed](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/pull/2228) in the current version.